# Meteor router doesn't render the template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I created a route and gave it a path to a template. But when I run the application, it says that 'there is no route'. Router simply doesn't follow the path. (I am sure the router package is installed because if I don't create and specify any route, on the main page appears the default message how to use a router)

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>todos</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{>todos}}
</body>

<template name="register">
    <h2>Register</h2>
</template>
```

route.js:

```
  Router.route('/register');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new project with just the code/markup (and adding iron:router) I see two errors in the browser console:

- Uncaught Error: No such template: todos
- Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: EJSON is not defined (truncated)

So the first one is simple - add a template called todos, or remove the markup that includes it.

And the second error is being thrown by iron:router.  It must have a dependency on the ejson package that is no longer included by default in the meteor base packages.

```
meteor add ejson
```

Will fix this, and the /register route will then work.