# Meteor Iron Router Not Loading Template ((Possibly deprecated))

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

None of the other questions on here answered my problem, maybe mine is a little different because I think this could be due to a package issue or something changing in the default Meteor Applications.

**HTML**

```
<template name="mainLayout">
    <header>
        <div class="siteTitle">
            <h1> Title of App </h1>
            <blockquote>
                No application runs better!
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="/"> Home </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="/name"> Test Routes </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="main">
        {{> yield}}
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p> Copyrights 2015 - David Davis - Meteor Test Dev </p>
    </footer>
</template>

<template name="home">
    <h2> Test </h2>
    <p> Test Message </p>
</template>

<template name="name">
    <form class="somePost">
        <label> What is your Name? </label>
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Ex: John Smith III" />

        <label> Do you like Meteor? </label>
        <select>
            <option value="true">  Yes </option>
            <option value="false"> No </option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</template>
```

**Routes**

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.route('/name', function () {
  this.render('name') },
  { name: 'name' }
);
```

**Packages**

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

#autopublish             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)

iron:router             # Iron Router for setting up multiple views / URIs
manuelschoebel:ms-seo   # SEO - Customize Titles

# Aldeed Database Information

aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
```

**NOTE**

This same code works fine on an older version of meteor that I have that uses the meteor-platform package which is now deprecated.

**WORKING PACKAGES**

This is the working set of packages that works when the code is run.

```
meteor-platform
autopublish
insecure

iron:router
aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
manuelschoebel:ms-seo
fourseven:scss
accounts-ui
accounts-password
alanning:roles
```

Comment: You haven't told us anything about how it fails (blank screen, throws exceptions, etc) and this is not a [mcve].  Anyway, try meteor add ejson and see if that resolves things (iron:router depends on this package, which is no longer included by default).  If now, edit your question to provide the above.

Comment: I'll try to push something up on to meteor pad if the ejson doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: ejson fixed the problem.  Is there a list of the packages that are no longer included by default?

Comment: https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI

Comment: @JeremyK  Thanks for the help and that link was great.  Do you want to post something in the answer section so I can give you the checkmark?

Comment: No, that's fine.  This actually needs to be flagged as a duplicate, (along with the other 10 or so).  I'll flag it, but glad your good now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor router doesn't render the template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912767/meteor-router-doesnt-render-the-template)

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry about the duplicate, I read about 12 or 14 questions before choosing to write one.